# Rails iteration over arrays and hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops, iteration

I am trying to iterate over what I think is a hash in rails. I used deep_pluck gem to get the values of a Model including some values from the associations. Like this:

```
    Continent.deep_pluck(:link_name, :name, 'countries' => [:link_name, :name])
```

this returns:

```
   [{"link_name"=>"europe", "name"=>"europe", "countries"=>[{"link_name"=>"countryname", "name"=>"countryname"}]}]
```

I am trying to iterate this like this:

```
             <% results.each do |continent| %>
              <% continent.each do |link_name, name, countries| %>
                <%= link_name %>
              <% end %>

            <% end %>
```

which in return this:

```
                link_name
                name
                countries
```

I tried a lot of different ways and methods and I still can't get the desired output which is to print out the values of :link_name and :name and also another object of countries to iterate them over again for their name etc.

I'm trying to build a navigation menu which has a list of each continent with a submenu of the countries of the continent. I use pluck because I just want the names and link_names of the database.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

When you iterate over a hash, you get access to the keys and values.

If you look at what's printing out, you're getting the keys of each hash.  Your output might make more sense if you set the parameters to what they actually are.

```
<% results.each do |continent| %>
  <% continent.each do |key, value| %>
    <%= key %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This should be enough to get you further along.  To achieve what you want, you'll need to check each `key` and do something with the `value` based on what the key is.

Comment: Thank you very much, i tried that and end up that I have to use continent["link_name"]

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try something like:

```
[{"link_name"=>"europe", "name"=>"europe", "countries"=>[{"link_name"=>"countryname", "name"=>"countryname"}]}].each do |continent|
  continent.each do |k,v|
    case k
    when 'countries'
      v.each do |country|
        country.each do |k,v| 
          puts "  - #{v}"
        end
      end
    else
      puts v
    end
  end
end
```

(Naturally, you'll need to add the `erb` markup. And the "puts" are just for example to run this in console.)

Which will give you:

```
europe
europe
  - countryname
  - countryname
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your suggestions, i finally managed to make it work like this:

```
      <% results.each do |continent| %>
             <li class="has_children"><a href="/continents/<%= continent["link_name"] %>"><%= continent["name"] %></a>
              <ul class="sub_menu">
                <% continent["countries"].each do |country| %>
            <li><a href="/countries/<%= country["link_name"] %>"><%= country["name"] %></a>
                <% end %>


              </ul>

             </li>

            <% end %>
```